# How to add language indicator?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

I have Ubuntu 11.10. I have installed gnome-classic using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

The problem is, the top panel doesn't show the language I am using right now (I use 3 different languages) so when I switch between languages (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>), nothing changes or indicates the current language on the top panel.

Any ideas or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take the pointer to the panel,
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**Right mouse click** the panel if you are Gnome-Classic 
or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+**Right mouse click** the panel if you are using Gnome Classic (No Effects) i.e. *gnome fallback mode*
Choose  *Add to Panel*  and look for "Keyboard indicator" and add it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, no keyboard indicator is in the add to panel window!

Comment: Please, check value of org.gnome.libgnomekbd.indicator using dconf Editor. May be the applet are running already in notification area but invisible because some settings (for example show-flags: true , try to change on show-flags: false)